# What Cache method should we use IOS app

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

Hi i have read about cache policy but still not quite clear. My purpose is to set request cache 3 minutes. Response cache 3 minutes. keep old cache for 1 day. What is the implementation that we should we use? Is there any setting that we can change beside those default bellow? (I use AFNetworking 3 for request and response). Any help is much appreciate. Thanks

```
NSURLRequestCachePolicy

NSURLRequest has a cachePolicy property, which specifies the caching behavior of the request according to the following constants:

NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy: Caching logic defined in the protocol implementation is used for a particular URL load request. This is the default policy.
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData: Data should be loaded from the originating source. No existing cache data should be used.
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData: Not only should the local cache data be ignored, but proxies and other intermediates should be instructed to disregard their caches so far as the protocol allows.
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad: Existing cached data should be used, regardless of its age or expiration date. If there is no existing data in the cache corresponding to the request, the data is loaded from the originating source.
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad: Existing cache data should be used, regardless of its age or expiration date. If there is no existing data in the cache corresponding to the request, no attempt is made to load the data from the originating source, and the load is considered to have failed, (i.e. “offline” mode).
NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData: Existing cache data may be used provided the origin source confirms its validity, otherwise the URL is loaded from the origin source.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost invariably use NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy unless you're trying to kill caching entirely for some reason.

The cache durations should be set by the server as part of its response (in the `Cache-Control` header).  The iOS URL cache obeys the policies specified in that header.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. is there any example of customization NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy to change the property?

Comment: You mean to change the Cache-Control header on its way into the cache?  I don't know if there's an example of it, but you'd presumably do it by implementing the `URLSession:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:` delegate method and creating a new **NSCachedURLResponse** object based on a modified **NSURLResponse** object that contains different header values.

Comment: Yes I mean customize to use own implementation of Cache if server does not support cached in header (to set cache time, size, validity period...)

Comment: Yeah, you can do what I described above and inject the header yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try to implement the above. Do you know any example or tutorial that we can follow?

Comment: Only the one in the conceptual doc, which doesn't really cover that particular type of modification: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Concepts/CachePolicies.html

Comment: the document is using NSURLConnection which is depreciated. Sound  we need to find another reference

Comment: NSURLSession's delegate method works almost exactly the same way, but instead of returning the NSCachedURLResponse object, you call the provided callback and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to create an implementation. can help me see whether it is correct and how to set the cache expire time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38865075/implement-custom-cache-for-afnetworking-3-x