# Implement custom cache for AFNetworking 3.x

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking

Hi I'm writing a IOS api to fetch data from server using AFNetworking 3.x My Server does not support caching. This this server header

```
Connection →Keep-Alive
Content-Length →4603
Content-Type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date →Wed, 10 Aug 2016 04:03:56 GMT
Keep-Alive →timeout=5, max=100
Server →Apache/2.4.18 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/5.4.45
X-Powered-By →PHP/5.4.45
```

I want to build custom API to enable cache (for example request and response should be cache for 10 second so that if user make same request, cache data is used. If cache expired  app will then re download again)

My `AFNetworking` Singleton

```
#pragma mark - Shared singleton instance

+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ((self = [super initWithBaseURL:url])) {
        self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    }
    return self;
}
```

My JSON request

```
- (void)sendJSONRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
                success:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject))success
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer].acceptableContentTypes;
    self.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval = 5;
    self.requestSerializer.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad;

        [self setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull dataTask, NSCachedURLResponse * _Nonnull proposedResponse) {
            return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:proposedResponse.response
                                                            data:proposedResponse.data
                                                        userInfo:proposedResponse.userInfo
                                                   storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
        }];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [ApiClient.sharedInstance dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            failure(error);
        } else {
            NSDictionary *jsonDict  = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
            success(response,jsonDict);
            NSLog(@"Success URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Success %@",jsonDict);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

How to modify the bellow code to enable caching request and response (I want response to be keep like 10 sec) (Or 1 day if no internet connection) Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

```
[self setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse * _Nonnull(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session, NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull dataTask, NSCachedURLResponse * _Nonnull proposedResponse) {
            return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:proposedResponse.response
                                                            data:proposedResponse.data
                                                        userInfo:proposedResponse.userInfo
                                                   storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
        }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
            return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:proposedResponse.response
```

do

```
            NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [proposedResponse.response.allHeaderFields mutableCopy];
            dictionary[@"Cache-Control" = ...
            NSHTTPURLResponse *modifiedResponse =
              [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc initWithURL:proposedResponse.response.URL
                                         statusCode:proposedResponse.response.statusCode
                                        HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1"
                                       headerFields:modifiedHeaders];

            [modifiedResponse 
            return [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:modifiedResponse
```

Note that it is not possible to retrieve the HTTP version from the original request.  I'm pretty sure I filed a bug about that.  I'm also pretty sure that it doesn't have any effect on anything, and I don't think it even gets stored in the underlying object, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Is the ideal is to grab the response header. Add field for @"Cache-control"? is the correct way is for ex: dictionary[@"Cache-Control" = @"max-age = 120, public". can we pass nil for HTTPVersion. Does it work on HTTPS?

Comment: Yes to the first question; you just set a string as the value for that header field.  I don't know about passing nil for the HTTP version.  And as far as I know, HTTPS has no effect on caching whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification will implement that. How to set the disk cache and memory cache capacity. What is the default value. Is this enough for normal web traffic (JSON, Image...)?

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on that.  It depends too highly on what your app is doing.  The best thing to do is probably to experiment with various sizes and see how it behaves in your particular app.

Comment: But I dont see how we can change cache size (for both disk cache and memory cache)

Comment: In the session configuration, provide your own NSURLCache object, e.g. `[[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:3000 diskCapacity:3000 diskPath:@"/path/to/cache"]` except using an actual writable path and probably not those arbitrary values.  :-)